# Haskell. Keeping track of indices in order to generate a new list

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, list-comprehension

I decided to learn Haskell and also learn to think in a more functional way, so I'm trying to solve very simple exercises trying to use a good approach in this paradigm.

I'm trying to achieve this simple exercise in Haskell:

```
Input: [2, 4, 1, 1, 2]
Output: [True, True, False, False, False, False, True, False, True, True]
```

So, the elements in the `Input` list will fall to be `False` in the
`Output` list, and the odd elements will be `True`; for each one
repeated as much times as the value on the `Input` list indicates.

Traverse the `Input` list, if the *i* ᵗʰ item is in a pair
position, append to output `True` *i* times to `Output`; if the
*i* ᵗʰ item is in an odd position, append `False` *i* times
to the `Output` list.

It seems to be a very simple problem, and it is. But for me, without any
functional programming background, I don't know how to express that
in Haskell.

I tried to keep track of the current index by using a λ-function
within the list comprehension.

```
    row :: [Integer] -> [Bool]
    row xs = [ (last $ zipWith (\i x -> x) [1..] [0..i]) `mod` 2 == 0
                | j <- xs, i <- [0..j-1] ]
```

But I'm not understanding its behavior, so I ended using `findIndices`
as a quick alternative:

```
    row :: [Integer] -> [Bool]
    row xs = [ (head $ findIndices (==j) (xs)) `mod` 2 == 0
                | j <- xs, i <- [0..j-1] ]
```

Using this last approach it seems OK:

```
    > let xs = [ 1, 4, 3, 2 ]
    > print $ row xs
    [True,False,False,False,False,True,True,True,False,False]
```

but the problem is not solved, for the items are not necessarily unique:

```
    > let xs = [ 2, 2, 4, 3]
    > print $ row xs
    [True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,False,False,False]
```

because `head findIndices` only gives the first of the occurrences.
(Though I think, event that if worked, that's not a very efficient way
of solving this problem.)

How can I achieve the result I'm looking for in a *Haskellian* way?

Comment: I think your example output should be changed. You are missing one false for the 4.

Comment: You're not appending true/false i times, right?  you're appending it list[i] times.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to transform each element in the input list into a sequence of as many equal `Bool`s as the element says, and you want the `Bool` be `True` if the index of the number in the input list is even, and `False` if the index is odd.

For that, you don't need the index, and it is better avoided - that gives simpler and usually more efficient code. The point is that the value alternates, it has a periodic pattern. To construct such periodic patterns, the Prelude offers the useful

```
cycle :: [a] -> [a]

Prelude> take 10 $ cycle [1,2,3]
[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1]
Prelude> take 10 $ cycle [True,False]
[True,False,True,False,True,False,True,False,True,False]
```

Neat, that's exactly what we need.

Now, we can pair up each element of the input list with the corresponding `Bool`:

```
[  2,    2,   4,   3]
[True,False,True,False,...
```

We could use `zip` to produce pairs, `[(2,True), (2,False), ...]` and then use a function that transforms the pair into the appropriate sequence of `Bool`s.

But that pattern is so common that we have a special higher-order function for that, `zipWith`.

So if the type of list elements is `Int`, we can write

```
row :: [Int] -> [Bool]
row xs = concat $ zipWith replicate xs (cycle [True,False])
```

For the type `Integer`, we can't use `replicate`, but we can use `genericReplicate` from `Data.List`.

Comment: Using `cycle` gives a more natural approach. I was too much focused on the parity of the index. Defining functions like that there is no need to add any comments in the code.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you already figured out that you can use `zip` to pair the elements with their indices. For each index `i` and the corresponding element `n`, you want to produce `n` copies of a boolean value (with `replicate`) and this boolean value depends on whether `i` is odd or even. This means `map`ping each tuple `(i, n)` to a list of booleans, so you get a list of lists (`[[Bool]]`). The last step is merging those lists with `concat` (which can be combined with the `map` into `concatMap`).

```
row = concatMap (\(i, n) -> replicate n (odd i)) . zip [1..]
```

Or if you don't like the pointfree style:

```
row xs = concatMap (\(i, n) -> replicate n (odd i)) (zip [1..] xs)
```

Comment: Very well explained. It's much easier that I thought and your explanation gives so much clarification. Definitely I'm not thinking in Haskell... yet.

Comment: Or `concat . zipWith (flip replicate) (cycle [True, False])`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution

```
row :: [Integer] -> [Bool]
row ns = r' True ns
    where
        r' :: Bool -> [Integer] -> [Bool]
        r' b (n:ns) = replicate b n : r' (not b) ns
        r' b   []   = []
```

(Not tested)

Comment: This on is almost good. The only problem that I can see is that `:` should be replaced with `++`.

Comment: You're right. I see that you've added a corrected version in a post.

Answer (score 1):

```
row :: [Integer] -> [Bool]
row xs = row' xs True

row' [] _ = []
row' (x:xs) b = (replicate x b) ++ (row' xs (not b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i would do this.

```
row [] = []
row xs = row' xs 0
   where row' xs i
            | i >= length xs    = []
            | otherwise         = (take (xs !! i) (repeat (isOdd i))) ++ (row' xs (i+1))


isOdd n = n `rem` 2 == 1
```

But I don't have ghc on this computer to test it.

Comment: Seems to work fine, you just need to put in a `concat`. However, this is IMO a task that shouldn't be done with explicit accumulator recursion, the OP was already on a better path.

Comment: Also, there is no need to define your own `isOdd` because `odd` is already in Prelude.

Answer (score 0):

I interepret

> Traverse the Input list, if the i ᵗʰ item is in a pair position,
>   append to output True i times to Output; if the i ᵗʰ item is in an odd
>   position, append False i times to the Output list.

I see two ways to interpret this. "For all elements, if the i-th element is even, return True i times. Otherwise, return false i times" or "For all elements, an i-th element conaining (v :: Int) should return True v times if i is even or False v times if i is odd". The second already has a satisfactory answer so I will give one for the first.

Some people like to reference indices but in this case you don't need to worry about the indicies. You can determine how many `Bool`s without counting how many elements you have traversed.

```
accum f (x:[]) = [x]
accum f (x:xs) = (x):(map f (accum f xs))
```

This function takes a function `f` and a list. It applies `f` to every element but the first, then makes a recursive call to the tail of the list, which again applies `f` to each remaining element, etc... The result is this :

```
accum (+1) [1,1,1,1,1]
[2,3,4,5,6]
```

The function `+1` is applied twice to the 2nd elem, thrice to the 2nd, etc.
Now how does this help us you ask? Well we can do this:

```
accum (\x -> [head x] ++ x) $ map (\x -> [x]) [2, 4, 1, 1, 2]
[[2],[4,4],[1,1,1],[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2,2]]
```

We first transform each element into a list with a single item. The we `accum` with the lambda you see above, which concatenates the head to the list. We can now directly convert to `Bool`s without further manipulations.

```
(map . map) odd $ accum (\x -> [head x] ++ x) $ map (\x -> [x]) [2, 4, 1, 1, 2]
[[False],[False,False],[True,True,True],[True,True,True,True],[False,False,False,False,False]]
```

You want `[Bool]` and not `[[Bool]]` so simply `concat`. Note that you can `concat` first, then use `map` instead of `map . map` :

```
map odd $ concat $ accum (\x -> [head x] ++ x) $ map (\x -> [x]) [2, 4, 1, 1, 2]
```